# WordPress only display on Child & Grandchild Pages

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to only show a sidebar widget on the parent page, and on any child and grandchild pages but with the code I have, it doesn't work for the grandchild pages.

```
    <?php if (is_page(8) || $post->post_parent=="8") { ?>
    //Do something
<?php } else { ?>
          //Do something else
<?php }?>
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the ancestors of the parent:

```
$ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);
```

Then ask with if current postID is in that array or not:

```
if( in_array(8, $ancestors) || is_page(8) || (8 == $post->post_parent)  ) :

   //do your thing

endif;
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much Marco. Very much appreciated; and such a simple snippet. Thanks again, worked perfectly.